# Computer requirements for an RTOS

Tags: operating-system, real-time, freertos

Are there any specific requirements in terms of the computer hardware (CPU/Mainboard/RAM/ etc.) to run an RTOS? Is it possible for any x86 CPU to do that or does it need specific features ? I was reading for example that freeRTOS supports "[any x86 compatible running in Real mode only](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS_ports.html)" - what is that real mode the CPU needs to be able to run in?

Answer (score 1):

The protected mode [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Mode) was introduced with 80286 architecture to extend the accessable memory range to 16MiB including segmentation. With the 80386 architecture it was further extended to 4Gib and paging was also added.

FreeRTOS needs a flat-memory-model, meaning that the whole memory can be directly addressed (without segmentation and paging), and this is for x86 architecture only the real-mode.